# C# command-line arguments and ls

Tags: c#, .net, bash, ls, msys

I'm using [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) to get some semblance of a sane scriptable shell on Windows :).

Now I'm writing a console application, written in C#, that accepts a number of arguments and presents those as options to the user in a dialog box. The actual options correspond to file names, that I'm retrieving with ls.

However, trouble appears when I have file names with spaces in them. Let's say I have files named:

```
file name
with spaces
```

In a directory called foo, my C# executable is called bar, and inside I inspect the contents of the "argv" array (i.e., the command-line arguments passed to my application, as interpreted by .NET).

The following strangeness happens when I call it:

./bar.exe "file name" "with spaces" -->

```
file name
with spaces
```

./bar.exe $(ls foo) -->

```
file
name
with
spaces
```

./bar.exe $(ls -Q foo) -->

```
"file
name"
"with
spaces"
```

Does anyone know what is happening here? Apparently, .NET is not parsing the arguments as passed by either bash or ls correctly.

But even when I add quotes, the quotes are included in the arguments instead of combining two arguments into one.

Is there even a way for me to get at the unprocessed command-line, so I can see if there's funkiness happening with control characters or something?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.CommandLine` to get the original command. Not sure about the bash stuff, sorry; maybe something involving line-endings (CR vs LF vs CRLF vs LFCR).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are passing Parameters in command line and Command line reads each word as separate Parameter , ; Try doing "File Name" "With Spaces" .. 
if you are passing it through code Use

```
ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "\"File Name \"" ;
```

as arguments to your Process

Answer (score -1):

I used this in my project using [RegawMOD.Android](http://www.regawmod.com/software/windows/androidlib/current/documentation/html/a20daf82-f181-08ac-e563-13ca3e92327b.htm) library

```
Device device = android.GetConnectedDevice(android.ConnectedDevices[0]);

objArray = new object[] { "ls", string.Concat("/sdcard/")) };

str = Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand(device, "shell", objArray));
// or 
// str= Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand("shell",objArray));
```

For more Command options check out this [Commands](http://spblinux.de/2.0/doc/ls.html)

Comment: @Rahil that edit did not make the post better. user: you seem not to have understood the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I wasn't sure about the `device` Class instance.

Comment: I meant the whitespace change, and the same goes for @Lorenzo's edit. The formatting of this post is just fine as-is, it doesn't get any more readable by inserting random newlines.